# Read Bluetooth RSSI on Windows 7/Vista/XP

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, bluetooth, rssi

I need to read the RSSI of the Bluetooth link on a Windows desktop - ideally Windows 7 and XP, but would be enough Windows 7 too. From what I studied in Windows CE and Mobile, there is a method in the Microsoft Bluetooth stack API called BthReadRSSI, but for desktop I couldn't found anything yet.

Does anybody have an workarround solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is that in Windows if you are using MS Bluetooth driver stack you cannot get the RSSI. This apply for Windows dekstop versions: XP, Vista and 7. The MS stack works on the principle that they have link or they don't have link, and not taking in account the quality level of the signal. Relevant information can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wdk/thread/7f0cc876-3998-4230-8343-3820463a0672).

Note: Windows CE bluetooth API contains a method for reading the RSSI, probably it was introduced because the device manufacturers asked for this feature.