# Determine distance of Bluetooth device on Windows7 Desktop

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth application written in C# . I use Win32 + Microsoft Bluetooth stack . I also use the In the Hand Bluetooth Library [(link)](http://32feet.codeplex.com/)

Now i want to measure the `nearness` of a connected device to my PC . By nearness i mean how far(distance) the device is from my pc or how strong the bluetooth connection between the device and my pc is ... Any of the two appoaches is acceptable as long as i am able to do some sort of a meaningful classification ..

So the problem is

a ) I could not find any API that can tell me how far my bluetooth device is from the pc .

b ) I came to know about RSSI and found all about it . Unfortunatley The RSSI api on WIN32+Microsoft Windows stack is unsupported . Similar question here [Read Bluetooth RSSI on Windows 7/Vista/XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790081/read-bluetooth-rssi-on-windows-7-vista-xp)

So i ask if there is any way to classify neighbourhood bluetooth devices ? I dont mind using any third party library to do so .